# Docker 4.1.1 on Mac missing Docker Compose V2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to have Docker Compose V2 on my machine, but for some reason it is not being installed with Docker Desktop 4.1.1., even though [it should](https://docs.docker.com/compose/cli-command/#install-on-mac-and-windows). Under Preference > Experimental features there is no option to "Use Docker Compose V2", which my colleagues have.

[image: Docker Desktop 4.1.1]

[image]

I'm on a MacBook Pro 2018 (Intel) with the latest Big Sur 11.6.

Im stumped. Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose`.